# Matlab - adding a timer to a graph

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, timer, figure

I am need to add a timer to a graph in matlab and dynamically update, similar to shown in picture. It will not run in real time, with 1 minute equal to around 1 second of real time. It needs to run for a full day. I have tried to do this with a legend but have not been able to get the variables to work properly.

[image]

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You can use a `'text'` [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) and update the [`'string'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#property_string) as your simulation runs. I would imagine that's how the other information is being displayed. Either that or [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a code like the following, where the "set" allows you to change the the string of the text object.

```
figure;
plot(0:1,0:1);
posX = 0.2;
posY = 0.5;
txtTime = text(posX, posY, 's', 'fontsize', 16);
for i = 1:10
    timeSimulation = 5*i;
    set(txtTime , 'string', [num2str(timeSimulation) 's']);
    pause(0.5);
end
```